# API Request Limits

Tags: api, governorlimits, limits

I have read the article: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.salesforce_app_limits_cheatsheet.meta/salesforce_app_limits_cheatsheet/salesforce_app_limits_platform_api.htm

Can someone, please, clarify to me, if only API requests coming **FROM** org count against limit?

Or do both API calls **FROM** and **INTO** org (external callouts) count against this limit?

Comment: I think it is only for calls **INTO** Salesforce

Comment: @BryanAnderson Thank you, I think you are right, I have created scratch org to test it and without making any callout from org I already have up to 100 API requests that I can see in Company Information.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The API call limits are those coming into Salesforce (e.g. when using the Apex Data Loader to load records). You can make as many outbound calls as you'd like, so long as you do not exceed any concurrency limits. Note that the third-party being called may have its own rate limits, so you'd need to consult the documentation for that service. For Salesforce-to-Salesforce API calls, only the org being called will use one API count, and the calling org will not.

Comment: Well said @sfdcfox

Comment: Thank you very much for clarification!